# Определение падежа

Tags: падежи

В предложении "Дождик целый день поливает двор", - слово "день" в каком падеже?

Answer (score 3):

Это **винительный падеж со значением меры времени**: ехать час, читать книгу всю ночь.

Беспредложный В.п. со значением кратности, меры времени и расстояния может употребляться с переходными и непереходными глаголами: повторить два раза, весить тонну, пройти километр.

В предложении эта падежная форма является обстоятельством.